# Dynamic JSON Parsing using T-SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, sql-server-json

I have a highly-unstructured JSON string, coming as a response of calling a REST API:

```json
{
    "info": "Test Json Structure",
    "Owner": "Self-Owned",
    "managedObjects": [{
            "Name": "Device1",
            "Class": "A"
        }, {
            "Name": "Device2",
            "Class_145": "Ax01",
            "Class_11": "B",
            "Type_125478": {
                "Model": "1",
                "Manufacturer": "External"
            },
            "Type_SD": {
                "Model": "00",
                "Manufacturer": "Internal"
                }
        }, {
            "Name": "Device3",
            "Class_x": "Cx11",
            "Class_T": "C8Y",
            "Type": {
                "Model": "1x",
                "Manufacturer": "Internal"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I dynamically parse this object using T-SQL, so that all child elements to represent columns of a table? More importantly, how to deal with `Type`, `Type_125478`, `Type_SD` objects, where in fact they have the same structure (`Model, Manufacturer`) but some how their names are different. Also keep in mind that the device may send a new identifier (`Type_XYZ`), which didn't exist before, but luckily has the same structure (`Model, Manufacturer`).

Comment: So each time you would have a different number of columns as a result of the query, depending on whether you get many `"Class_145"`, `"Class_11"`s or not?

Comment: I think it's better to have such types as type_name and type_value instead of many columns since you can have only fixed layout of resultset

Comment: @GSerg one solution to this is to create the full set of columns, and columns which match the json will have values, others will have NULL .. this is what R does when parsing such dynamic string. The question is how to do the same in T-SQL

Comment: @astentx that would simplify the problem for sure, but I have no control over the source in the way it sends the data

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? JSON support was introduced with v2016.

Comment: @khidir What will you do with such multivalue relation as in object 2. There is two classes and two types, should this be different columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use something like this to explode the *whole lot* into a tabular structure and proceed with this (needs a SQL-Server version v2016+):

```
DECLARE @YourJSON NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'{
    "info": "Test Json Structure",
    "Owner": "Self-Owned",
    "managedObjects": [{
            "Name": "Device1",
            "Class": "A"
        }, {
            "Name": "Device2",
            "Class_145": "Ax01",
            "Class_11": "B",
            "Type_125478": {
                "Model": "1",
                "Manufacturer": "External"
            },
            "Type_SD": {
                "Model": "00",
                "Manufacturer": "Internal"
                }
        }, {
            "Name": "Device3",
            "Class_x": "Cx11",
            "Class_T": "C8Y",
            "Type": {
                "Model": "1x",
                "Manufacturer": "Internal"
            }
        }
    ]
}';
```

--the query

```
SELECT A.info
      ,A.[Owner]
      ,C.[key] AS TagName
      ,CASE WHEN D.Model IS NULL THEN C.[value] END AS TagValue 
      ,D.Model
      ,D.Manufacturer
FROM OPENJSON(@YourJSON)
WITH(info NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[Owner] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,managedObjects NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(A.managedObjects) B
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(B.[value]) C
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(CASE WHEN ISJSON(C.[value])=1 THEN C.[value] END) 
WITH (Model NVARCHAR(MAX)
     ,Manufacturer NVARCHAR(MAX))D;
```

--the result

```
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
| info                | Owner      | TagName     | TagValue | Model | Manufacturer |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
| Test Json Structure | Self-Owned | Name        | Device1  |       |              |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
| Test Json Structure | Self-Owned | Class       | A        |       |              |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
| Test Json Structure | Self-Owned | Name        | Device2  |       |              |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
| Test Json Structure | Self-Owned | Class_145   | Ax01     |       |              |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
| Test Json Structure | Self-Owned | Class_11    | B        |       |              |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
| Test Json Structure | Self-Owned | Type_125478 |          | 1     | External     |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
| Test Json Structure | Self-Owned | Type_SD     |          | 00    | Internal     |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
| Test Json Structure | Self-Owned | Name        | Device3  |       |              |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
| Test Json Structure | Self-Owned | Class_x     | Cx11     |       |              |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
| Test Json Structure | Self-Owned | Class_T     | C8Y      |       |              |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
| Test Json Structure | Self-Owned | Type        |          | 1x    | Internal     |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
```

Hint: You might add `B.[key]` to the result as an object identifier.

The idea in short

- We use a first `OPENJSON` to get into your JSON. The `WITH`-clause allows to address the JSON-props as columns. We return the `managedObejcts` as JSON themselve.
- We use one more `OPENJSON` to dive into the managed objects.
- This will return an array of objects. We can pass the `value` into another `OPENJSON`.
- Whenever the `value` can be interpreted as JSON on its own, we use one more `OPENJSON`, this time with a `WITH`-clause again to get the internal props as columns.

You can insert this result into a table (declared, temp, physical...) and continue with this *easy-to-read* set.

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo that actually worked, as I am using SQL Server 2017..